# Building Google api client within Fragment

Tags: android-studio, google-api-client

I am getting an error while building google api client in a fragment. The error I am getting is;

```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: net.janusjanus.we4x4_v1.upload cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener
```

I have implemented `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`, `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`, and `LocationListener`

and requesting the build as following;

```
         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) getActivity())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
```

first I had a problem declaring the new GoogleApiClient.Builder where I declared it as ;

```
          mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
```

underlined as an error, thus I had to try several ways to declare it, with `getActivity()` and `getContext()`. but I got the same error ?

Any idea on what I am doing wrong here and the correct way ?

Answer (score 1):

Well simply in my case i had to declare the GoogleApiClient.Builder as following;

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(UploadPictures.this.getContext())
```

where UploadPictures is the fragment name.

Hope this could be helpful for someone.

Comment: `UploadPictures.this` would have been sufficient, I guess

Answer (score 0):

implement GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, and LocationListener

```
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        }
```

And then change code to:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
```